# How can i add notifications to a meteor app built for iOS and android?

Tags: meteor

Also how can a notification be kept in the notification panel for a certain time period? (eg. uber app has 'incoming cab' notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of packages: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=push

This is the most popular: https://atmospherejs.com/raix/push

Here is *one* of the guides: http://stached.io/standalone/fBLmRhsAuPSxKBSgM